# White spot on camera LCD

Tags: olympus, lcd, spots

I recently got the Olympus OMD EM10 MII and while I was trying to take some pics last night, I saw two very tiny white spots on the LCD screen of the camera when I faced the night sky. When I took few pics, the spots didn't show up on my photos (I did not look the photos in my computer but on my LCD screen). But, when I try to view on the LCD, the two tiny spots are still there. I was wondering if this is common and can be fixed or is the camera faulty and I need to return it? If it can be fixed, can someone please guide me. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

The screen on the back of a digital camera is essentially a miniature computer screen. The artifact you are noticing is called a *hot-pixel*. They are common on screens and even though annoying they are not always considered a default unless there are many. Computer screen manufacturers sometimes have a specific guideline as to how many dead pixels are considered a defect, while also explicitly have a *zero dead pixel* policy. For cameras, I am unaware of any such policy, so I recommend you call Olympus to find out.